# How do I extract one key value pair from _consumeKafka_ in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-nifi, kafka-producer-api

I want to use *consumeKafka* in Nifi to consume a topic. From that, I want to take out a key-value pair and put it into another Kafka topic using *PutKafka*. How do I achieve this and avoiding duplication on the basis of a particular key?

Answer (score 1):

If the message from the Kafka stream will be received in a standard format, it will be an easy thing to do. Following are the steps to do this if the receiving message is in JSON dormat.

- Configure `ConsumeKafka` to receive from a topic
- Use `EvaluateJsonPath` to parse and read the value for a particular key and and assign it to a NiFi FlowFile attribute
- Use `ReplaceText` processor to form your own message (that contains the parsed key) which you want to send to another Kafka topic
- Connect the flow with `PutKafka`

More details on EvaluateJsonPath can be found [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Dda-HHzVAAAuv54.jpg:large) and [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/118237/how-to-use-apache-nifi-evaluatejsonpath-for-json-t.html)

Comment: >Use EvaluateJsonPath to parse and read the value for a particular key and assign it to a NiFi FlowFile attribute

I could not find how to read the particular key.

Comment: EvaluateJsonPath lets you add dynamic properties. If you right click and click configure and go to the "Properties" tab, there will be a plus (+) button which lets you add dynamic attributes where the value will be a valid JSON expression like `$.sequence.key` to read `key` from `{"sequence" : {"key": "some-key"}}`